# How to interact with bluetooth device connected /paired to windows 10 pc?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, interaction

Before upgrading to windows 10 it was simple to connect and it used to show options for each individual device in device and Printers. Now in windows 10 it gives no option. Just shows device is paired and no way to interact with device.

Comment: Your question is very vague. What device is it? What interaction do you want? All devices will show up in device manager, but i'm not sure if that's what you want. If it's an audio device, for example, you'll get more options in playback device's (from the context menu on the volume icon). Please add more details to your question.

Comment: For eg i connected my mobile phone to my laptop and i want to play songs on my mobile via laptop speakers. So how do I do that?  After pairing the mobile device is visible in device manager however when I right click on the mobile device icon it only gives me options to create shortcut,troubleshoot or remove device. I mean it does not give any   options to transfer files with that device or play songs  on device via laptop speakers,etc. Earlier in Windows 7 right clicking the connected device used to give certain options to interact with the device. I hope you are getting the problem.

Comment: Oh, OK. Well I really didn't know that used to exist but maybe someone else can help you. Sorry.